# Having problem installing Wine ( Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: software-installation, wine, dependencies

I'm tryin' to install Wine on my Ubuntu 14.04 using Software Center and there is some stuff:

> Zależności dla następujących pakietów, nie zostały spełnione:
>
> unity-control-center: Depends: libpulse-mainloop-glib0 (>= 1:0.99.1)
>   ale 1:4.0-0ubuntu11.1 zostanie zainstalowany Depends: libpulse0 (>=
>   1:0.99.1) ale 1:4.0-0ubuntu11.1 zostanie zainstalowany Depends: libxi6
>   (>= 2:1.2.99.4) ale 2:1.7.1.901-1ubuntu1.1 zostanie zainstalowany
>   wine:

Google Translate version:

> According to the following packages have not been met:
>
> unity-control-center: Depends: libpulse-mainloop-glib0 (> = 1:
>   0.99.1), but 1: 4.0-0ubuntu11.1 will be installed Depends: libpulse0 (> = 1: 0.99.1), but 1: 4.0-0ubuntu11 .1 be installed Depends: libxi6
>   (> = 2: 1.2.99.4), but 2: 1.7.1.901-1ubuntu1.1 wine will be installed:

How to fix that?

Tried using terminal:

> Czytanie list pakietów... Gotowe Budowanie drzewa zależności Odczyt
>   informacji o stanie... Gotowe Nie udało się zainstalować niektórych
>   pakietów. Może to oznaczać, że zażądano niemożliwej sytuacji lub użyto
>   dystrybucji niestabilnej, w której niektóre pakiety nie zostały
>   jeszcze utworzone lub przeniesione z katalogu Incoming
>   ("Przychodzące"). Następujące informacje mogą pomóc rozwiązać
>   sytuację:
>
> Następujące pakiety mają niespełnione zależności: unity-control-center
>   : Wymaga: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) ale nie zostanie zainstalowany
>   Wymaga: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) ale nie zostanie zainstalowany wine :
>   Wymaga: wine1.6 lub wine1.8 ale nie zostanie zainstalowany E: Błąd,
>   pkgProblemResolver::Resolve zwrócił błąd, może to być spowodowane
>   zatrzymanymi pakietami.

Comment: Please, paste the command you used for the attempt, either. Btw, you can get english output by setting either `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`, or just `LANG=C`. For example: `LANG=C apt install wine`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to do it via terminal try to run the following. This will update your system and update dependencies and then install wine

```
sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade 
apt-get install wine
```

Comment: Didn't work, I put terminal quote in my question

Comment: Maybe try to do it using the following tutorial:

Comment: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/12/install-wine-1-8-stable-new-ppa/

Comment: same stuff, really don't know what to do